# How to specialize a class in Python (typing generics)

Tags: python, generics, typing

How to provide a different definition for a specialized (in `typing` sense) class?

Example, why that might be useful:

```
TElement = TypeVar('TElement')

class BaseCollection(Generic[TElement]):
    name: str
    data: List[TElement]

    def __add__(self, other: 'BaseCollection[TElement]'):
        return CombinedCollection[TElement].from_collections(self, other)
    ...

class Collection(BaseCollection):
    pass

# how do I do this specialization
class Collection[int](BaseCollection[int]):
    def sum(self):
        return sum(self.data)


# so that CombinedCollection[int] has also the sum method
class CombinedCollection(Collection[TElement]):
    @classmethod
    def from_collections(cls, *lists: Collection[TElement]):

        return CombinedCollection[TElement]('(' + '+'.join(l.name for l in lists) + ')', 
            [x for l in lists for x in l])

# i.e. I can do
c = Collection[int]('my_collection c', [1,2])
d = Collection[int]('my_collection d', [-1, -2, -3])

cd = c + d
# and now I can do this:
cd.sum()
# -3
cd.name
# (my_collection c+my_collection d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a way to do this, but instead of creating "specializations" of a class, you need to define all methods of a class in the class definition (which is what Python would look like, if without type annotations), and add a type constraint on the `self` parameter of the method:

```
class Collection(Generic[T]):
    def sum(self: "Collection[int]") -> int:
        ...

a = C[int]([1, 2, 3])
reveal_type(a.sum())  # int
b = C[str](["a", "b", "c"])
reveal_type(b.sum())  # error: Invalid self argument "C[str]" to attribute function "sum"
```

See a concrete example on [mypy-play](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=cbdd236f83aed9bc58ef06c947604ed4).

Note that this only works with concrete types and not type varaibles. If you replace `int` with a `TypeVar` with bounds (`TypeVar("T", bound=numbers.Real)`) or with constraints (`TypeVar("T", int, float)`), mypy seems to ignore them and will accept any type. This is also demonstrated in the example above. I believe this is a bug or an oversight.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense, thank you. Although if you wanted to provide different definitions for `sum` based on the type of self, you would need to do isinstance checks, but that's standard in Python, you only get the type hints, not static dispatch like in compiled languages.

Comment: Also thanks for that mypy-play link. Yes I also believe that's a bug. As for `def fn_typevar(self, other: "C[TNumber]") -> TNumber:` it indeed _does_ show the error if TNumber is instantiated by mypy with an invalid type (e.g. str). But when adding to that also the type hint to `self` it suddenly fails to report not only the `self` error, but also the `other` error.  Example: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=e21e80b76ca3ee8a4af05bcf80bc1e11

Comment: @Adam Ah interesting, thanks for the example. I would guess there's a bug related to how mypy infers `TypeVar` types for `self`, but I know too little of how mypy works to arrive at any conclusions.